# How a loop is mapped into the GPU, in blocks, warps and threads?

Tags: multithreading, gpu, openacc

I would need clarification on how a loop is mapped on the device, using OpenACC. I'm also not sure about the role of blocks, warps and threads.

If I have a loop like this:

```
#pragma acc parallel loop
for(i=0; i<1024; i++){
  vector[i] += 1;
}
```

And my GPU supports "maximum threads per block = 1024". **How the loop is parallelized into blocks?**
My first thought is that a single block is sufficient to handle the operations because the vector has 1024 elements. In this case, I think that the block is composed of 1024 threads, each one corresponding to the operation `vector[i] += 1;` with a different index `i`.

**Is my understanding of what a thread is correct?**

I would have so 32 warps of 32 threads. How are they executed? Can all of them run simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenACC itself doesn't prescribe the gang and vector mapping to the target device, this is done by the compiler implementation.  While you don't specify, my answer assumes you're using the NVIDA HPC Compilers (aka PGI) as oppose to GNU.

When targeting NVIDIA GPUs, a "gang" maps to a CUDA block and a "vector" maps to the x dimension of the thread block.  Since you haven't specified the vector length, the compiler is most likely using 8 gangs (blocks) with 128 vectors (threads) per gang.  You can verify this by adding the flag "-Minfo=accel" during compilation to see the compiler feed back messages and setting the environment variable "NV_ACC_TIME=1" to get a simple profile after the run.

If you want to force the compiler to use 1024 threads per block, add the clause "vector_length(1024)" to your parallel loop directive.  In this case, the performance wont matter between using a 1x1024 or 8x128 schedule, but give it try.

> I would have so 32 warps of 32 threads. How are they executed? Can all
> of them run simultaneously?

Yes, you would have a total of 32 warps, each with 32 threads.  A warp is executed in SIMT mode, Single Instruction Multiple Threads, meaning that all threads are executing the same instruction at the same time just on different data.

On an NVIDIA device, you have Streaming Multiprocessors (SM) where up to 2048 threads, or 64 warps, can be executing at the same time. Since you're only using 1024 threads, yes, these will be run simultaneously.

Note that the SM count varies by device, but for example a V100 has 80 SMs so using only half of one SM is severely under utilizing the device.